# OdbcConnection String

Tags: c#, odbc, database-connection

To establish an odbc Connection String in a Method, one could do it the following way:

```
odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection();
odbcConnection.Connection = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};"
+ "SERVER=localhost;PORT=3306;"
+ "DATABASE=dbdemo2;UID=demo-user";
```

Why does the DRIVER need to be mentioned in curly brackets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation

[OdbcConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
connection-string ::= empty-string[;] | attribute[;] | attribute; connection-string  
empty-string ::=  
attribute ::= attribute-keyword=attribute-value | DRIVER=[{]attribute-value[}]  
attribute-keyword ::= DSN | UID | PWD  
 | driver-defined-attribute-keyword  
attribute-value ::= character-string  
driver-defined-attribute-keyword ::= identifier
```

> Gets or sets the string used to open a data source.
>
> ...
>
> **Applications do not have to add braces around the attribute** value after the Driver keyword **unless the attribute contains a semicolon
>   (;), in which case the braces are required**. If the attribute value
>   that the driver receives includes braces, the driver should not remove
>   them but they should be part of the returned connection string.
>
> **A DSN or connection string value enclosed with braces ({}) that contains any of the characters []{}(),;?*=!@ is passed intact to the
>   driver**. However, when you use these characters in a keyword, the
>   Driver Manager returns an error when you work with file DSNs, but
>   passes the connection string to the driver for regular connection
>   strings. Avoid using embedded braces in a keyword value.
>
> The connection string may include any number of driver-defined
>   keywords. Because the DRIVER keyword does not use information from the
>   system, the driver must define enough keywords so that a driver can
>   connect to a data source using only the information in the connection
>   string. The driver defines which keywords are required to connect to
>   the data source.

In this case it probably doesn't need it, though there is no harm in adding braces